# Importing .3ds/.obj/.max/etc files into a Cocos3D project

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, mesh, cocos3d

Is it necessary to convert all of the above file formats into .pod before including them into Cocos3D? It seems like that used to be the case based on what I've been reading but most of those posts are from several years ago and so I am wondering if it is still valid.

So my question is two-fold

1) If it is possible to load in these file types directly, how would I go about doing that?

and

2) If it is not possible and I have to conver to .pod, what is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos3D currently only supports the POD model format. You can export directly from 3DS Max, Maya & Blender using the PVRGeoPOD export tool. See the [full instructions here](http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-importing-converting-collada-to-pod/) for more info.

For a step-by-step guide to downloading the PVRGeoPOD converter, and installing it into Blender, view Harry Dart-O’Flynn’s [Starting Cocos3d – 5 – Blender & PVRGeoPOD Exporter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYZaSBZ-Gc8&list=PLU4bmVOOYXK-fV0Wt-ES5n3k8qTTyqgYu&index=7) video tutorial.

Comment: You're the guy who created Cocos! Great product man and thank you for the answer. I will check out those links